# why cant I install windows server 2008 R2 on virtual machine?

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines

.when I want to install server 2008 in VMware workstation 8 in the step for selecting the os says to me:

> there aren't any option to choose .

and by clicking next button I got this error :

> "windows could not display the images available for installation".

what should I do ?

Comment: Which virtualization software?

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a corrupted ISO image; try downloading it again.

Answer (score 0):

[image]make sure by coping and install it on other windows like windows 7?

make sure about the version of your software

make sure your OS or Software compatible with x86 or x64 ?

Comment: I've checked it out .my windows is 7 x64 and the iso file is x64 and I have tried two or three times.but it's not working .

Comment: cracked? version?  in the middle of download broke? (disconnect?)

Comment: the version is Windows Server 2008 x64 R2.it's not cracked.I got that from Darolfonoon institude.

Comment: I would suggest as mentioned above by Massimo to re download the ISO file and try again - you most likely have a corrupt file.

Comment: no , iso image tested in another pc and working properly